# Controle de banco de dados (MySQL) em ambiente de produção

Tags: php, mysql, git, shell-script

Por boa parte de meu projeto vim trabalhando com repositório git em um servidor local, (Debian 7), essa semana migrei para o gitlab, sem nenhuma complicação na mudança, mudei apenas por questão de portabilidade, pois sempre estou trabalhando em um local ou outro fora da mesma rede.

Nessa migração, me deparei com um problema na questão do controle de meu banco de dados ja em produção.

O problema se da diretamente em que, em ambiente de produção, anteriormente, como o repositório ficava no mesmo servidor do banco de dados, eu possuía um script que lia o banco a cada 24 horas, e dava um dump nas tabelas com alterações em um estrutura de pastas separando por data (feito em PHP, coisa muito simples).

Algo como isso:

```
bd_bckps/
        /01-01-2017/..
                   /customers.sql
                   /logs.sql
        /02-01-2017/..
                   /logs.sql
                   /internal_users.sql
        /[prossegue os dias]
```

Passando para o gitlab, o backup do banco de dados continua funcionando, porém fora da estrutura de versão e fora do backup geral, além de que, futuras modificações no banco de desenvolvimento que devam ser upadas para produção ficarão fora do controle.

Bom, acredito que essa forma de controle de BD que eu use não seja muito segura,e é horrível quando eu preciso restaurar algo, pois é necessário averiguar quase que manualmente o que aconteceu.

A dúvida é:

> Existe algum modo de automatizar o push do git pra um determinado horário ? (Shel Script ?)

Ou:

> Qual método de controle de versão de banco de dados seria recomendado usar em um projeto com quantidade massivas de dados ?

PS.: Ainda não tinha trabalhado com um banco que fosse ficar tão grande, e, não tenho muita experiência com MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar o crontab, por exemplo todos os dias a meia noite, acessar a pasta /diretorio, fazer commit com data e horário corrente e o push)

```
0 0 * * * git add . && commit -m `date` && git push origin master  >/dev/null 2>&1
```